# Create a linked list from an array, and also free that list

Tags: c, array, linked-list

I'm currently learning C/C++ and I saw this question on Reddit on how to create a linked from an array and decided that would make a good exercise for learning the absolute basics of C, so without looking at the answers I wrote this.

Anyways, preamble aside, here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Node Node;

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
} Node;

Node *array_to_list(int32_t array[], int32_t length) {
    if (length <= 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Node* tail = NULL;

    for (int32_t i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Node* current = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        current->data = array[i];
        current->next = tail;
        tail = current;
    }

    return tail;
}

void free_list(Node *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        Node *next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Node *list = array_to_list(array, 5);

    Node *current = list;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

    free_list(list);

    return 0;
}
```

As of now this is all inside `main.c` and I didn't implement any other methods a linked list would normally have, I'm just trying to see if I'm doing things right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use the correct types

Use `size_t` instead of `int32_t` for the array size and index. Using `int32_t` will limit it to arrays containing 2,147,483,647 elements even if you compiled it for 64-bit mode.

Also, note that it does not make sense to check if `i` or `length` is less than zero since it is unsigned.

```
Node* array_to_list(int array[], size_t length) {
    // ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // ...
    }
    return tail;
}
```

## Check if malloc was successful

You cannot simply assume that there will be enough memory available.

## Putting it all together:

```
Node* array_to_list(int array[], size_t length) {
    Node* tail = NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Node* current = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (!current)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        current->data = array[length - 1 - i];
        current->next = tail;
        tail = current;
    }
    return tail;
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    struct Node* list = array_to_list(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
    for (Node* node = list; node; node = node->next)
        printf("%d\n", node->data);
    free_list(list);
}
```

Comment: Totally forgot about checking if malloc failed or not, but I think I'll still have to check if size isn't 0, because I need to loop over the array in reverse (so the linked list created is in the same order as the array), and if the length is 0 it'd underflow to 4294967295 and as such I'd index into an invalid place in the array

Comment: @MindSwipe, see my latest edit. You don't have to check if `length` is 0. `array[length - 1 - i]` reverses the array.

Comment: `Node* current = malloc(sizeof(Node));` could be `Node* current = malloc(sizeof(*current));`

Comment: @ggorlen potato, patata ;-)

Comment: Not quite -- there's benefit to the second approach. See [sizeof style: sizeof(type) or sizeof variable?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201104/sizeof-style-sizeoftype-or-sizeof-variable)

Comment: There are benefits and downsides to both approaches. `#define MALLOC(t, n) (t*)malloc(sizeof(t) * n)` eliminates the downsides.